# Mounting AWS Secrets Manager on Kubernetes/Helm chart

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, aws-secrets-manager, kubernetes-secrets

I have created an apps cluster deployment on AWS EKS that is deployed using Helm. For proper operation of my app, I need to set env variables, which are secrets stored in AWS Secrets manager. Referencing a [tutorial](https://www.eksworkshop.com/beginner/194_secrets_manager/sync_native_secrets_env/), I set up my values in `values.yaml` file someway like this

```
secretsData:
  secretName: aws-secrets
  providerName: aws
  objectName: CodeBuild
```

Now I have created a secrets provider class as AWS recommends: `secret-provider.yaml`

```
apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name: aws-secret-provider-class

spec:
  provider: {{ .Values.secretsData.providerName }}
  parameters:
    objects: |
      - objectName: "{{ .Values.secretsData.objectName }}"
        objectType: "secretsmanager"
        jmesPath: 
            - path: SP1_DB_HOST
              objectAlias: SP1_DB_HOST
            - path: SP1_DB_USER
              objectAlias: SP1_DB_USER
            - path: SP1_DB_PASSWORD
              objectAlias: SP1_DB_PASSWORD
            - path: SP1_DB_PATH
              objectAlias: SP1_DB_PATH
  secretObjects:
    - secretName: {{ .Values.secretsData.secretName }} 
      type: Opaque
      data:
        - objectName: SP1_DB_HOST
          key: SP1_DB_HOST
        - objectName: SP1_DB_USER
          key: SP1_DB_USER
        - objectName: SP1_DB_PASSWORD
          key: SP1_DB_PASSWORD
        - objectName: SP1_DB_PATH
          key: SP1_DB_PATH
```

I mount this secret object in my `deployment.yaml`, the relevant section of the file looks like this:

```
volumeMounts:
            - name: secrets-store-volume
              mountPath: "/mnt/secrets"
              readOnly: true
          env:
            - name: SP1_DB_HOST
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: {{ .Values.secretsData.secretName }}
                  key: SP1_DB_HOST
            - name: SP1_DB_PORT
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: {{ .Values.secretsData.secretName }}
                  key: SP1_DB_PORT
```

further down in same deployment file, I define `secrets-store-volume` as :

```
      volumes:
        - name: secrets-store-volume
          csi:
            driver: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
            readOnly: true
            volumeAttributes:
              secretProviderClass: aws-secret-provider-class
```

*All drivers are installed into cluster and permissions are set accordingly*

with `helm install mydeployment helm-folder/ --dry-run` I can see all the files and values are populated as expected. Then with `helm install mydeployment helm-folder/` I install the deployment into my cluster but with `kubectl get all` I can see the pod is stuck at `Pending` with warning `Error: 'aws-secrets' not found` and eventually gets timeout. In AWS CloudTrail log, I can see that the cluster made request to access the secret and there was no error fetching it. How can I solve this or maybe further debug it? Thank you for your time and efforts.

Answer (score 1):

`Error: 'aws-secrets' not found` - looks like CSI Driver isn't creating kubernetes secret that you're using to reference values

Since yaml files looks correctly, I would say it's probably CSI Driver configuration [Sync as Kubernetes secret](https://secrets-store-csi-driver.sigs.k8s.io/topics/sync-as-kubernetes-secret.html) - `syncSecret.enabled` (which is false by default)

So make sure that secrets-store-csi-driver runs with this flag set to true, for example:

```
helm upgrade --install csi-secrets-store \
--namespace kube-system secrets-store-csi-driver/secrets-store-csi-driver \
--set grpcSupportedProviders="aws" --set syncSecret.enabled="true"
```

Comment: Hi @mehowthe, thank you for your approach and it is very valid but sadly not the root of my problem. I had set the sync to be true beforehand it still will not work. I have opened an Issue on github meanwhile and I see others have similiar issues since a couple of days.

Comment: Did you manage to get this working. Fails for me as well and couldn’t find any pointers to fix it.